# How to deserialize array of guid ids received from cognito attribute

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, json.net, amazon-cognito

I have custom attribute in cognito used for mapping third party claims.

After mapping is completed(on user login) I receive values as string in this format

> [bf5ad010-8961-49d7-b068-87f23026f49d,
> 0080d0fe-6a19-4dfe-a472-09a3f93d7015]

I'm trying to deserialize this values on backend to list/array of strings, but since values in [] are not enclosed with "", deserialization fails with error message

> ''b' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $[0] | LineNumber: 0 |
> BytePositionInLine: 1.'

Anyone have idea how to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: If that is really what you get then you cannot parse it as json because it is not json. Just drop the first and last character and then split at `, `.

Comment: thanks, that works as solution but not the nice one :). These values are azure AD group ids, not sure if there is a way to map it to cognito as strings. That would be better way if someone is experienced with azure AD claims -> cognito custom attribute mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they are guid-type and custom ids, most likely there will be no other possibility besides this:

```
public static class GetClainCognito
{
    public static IEnumerable<Guid> GetIdClainCognito(this string value) => value.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split(",").Select(x => Guid.Parse(x));
}
```